# android application force close on this.startactivity(intent);

Tags: android

this is the source code i am using

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.AndroidLogo: 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddUser.class);
          this.startActivity(intent);
        break;
        case R.id.AndroidText: 
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, SearchUser.class);
              this.startActivity(intent2);
        break;
        } 
        return true; 
        }
```

Comment: What if you are using this source code..Elaborate your question. Post Logcat

Comment: Have added the AddUser and  SearchUser Activity in your manifest.xml file ? show your logcat error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not mentioned the classes in menifest you wanted to call ;Use these permission lines to call another activity in activity tag

```
 < android:enabled="true" android:name="AddUser"/>
```

for one first and 
for second class use another activity tag

```
<android:enabled="true" android:name="SearchUser"/>
```